# undefined reference to `vtable for implementation' error

Tags: c++, build, makefile

I wrote some c++ files and after compiling with out make file it works fine . But when using make file it pop out some errors . My codes are :

include directory files :

application.h

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include "employee.h"
#include "employee_data.h"
#include "employee.h"  

...some defintions here...

#endif
```

employee.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include "employee_data.h"  

#endif
```

employee_data.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_DATA_H
#define EMPLOYEE_DATA_H

typedef struct
{
 int    emp_id;     

 char   *name,
        *dept,
        *book,
        *time;  

 }employeedata;

 ...some codes here...
#endif
```

library.h

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include "employee_data.h"
#include "application.h"
using namespace std;

class Library
{

public:

virtual int addE() = 0;
virtual int  deleteE() = 0; 
virtual int issue() = 0 ;
virtual int returnB() = 0; 
virtual int employee() = 0;

};

class implementation : public Library
{

private:

employeedata *emp; /*structure object*/

public:

int addE();
int deleteE();
int issue();
int returnB();
int employee();

};

#endif
```

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H 
#define MAIN_H

#include "library.h"

class message
{
  public:

   void errormessage(int);
 }; 

#endif
```

and my src directory conatins .cpp files . It includes

main.cpp

```
 #include "main.h"
 #include "library.h" 
 #include "employee_data.h" 
 #include "application.h"

 int main()
 {
  message msg;
   /* codes here..../*
 }
```

library_function.cpp

```
 #include "library.h"
 #include "employee.h"
 #include "main.h"
 #include "application.h"
 #include "employee_data.h"

 int implementation :: addE() 
 {

 }

 etc..
```

error_function.cpp

```
  #include "main.h"

  void message :: errormessage(int errno)
  {

  }
```

employee_functions.cpp

```
  #include "employee.h"
  #include "main.h"
  ..some code...
```

display.cpp

```
  #include "employee_data.h"
  #include "application.h"
  ..some code..
```

thread.cpp

```
  #include "employee.h"
  #include "application.h"

   ...some code..
```

and my make file is :

```
CC=g++
FLAGS=-o
CFLAGES=-c -Wall
THREAD=-lpthread


INCLUDE=../include/
SRC=../src/
OBJ=../obj/
OUTPUT=../bin/


$(OUTPUT)vkp:$(OBJ)main.o $(OBJ)library_functions.o $(OBJ)employee_functions.o $(OBJ)display.o $(OBJ)error_function.o $(OBJ)thread.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) vkp $(OBJ)main.o $(OBJ)library_functions.o $(OBJ)employee_functions.o $(OBJ)display.o $(OBJ)error_function.o $(OBJ)thread.o $(THREAD)
    mv vkp $(OUTPUT)

$(OBJ)main.o:$(SRC)main.cpp $(INCLUDE)main.h $(INCLUDE)employee_data.h $(INCLUDE)application.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)main.cpp -I $(INCLUDE)
    mv main.o $(OBJ)

$(OBJ)library_functions.o:$(SRC)library_functions.cpp $(INCLUDE)library.h $(INCLUDE)employee.h $(INCLUDE)main.h $(INCLUDE)application.h $(INCLUDE)employee_data.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)library_functions.cpp -I $(INCLUDE)
    mv main.o $(OBJ)

$(OBJ)employee_functions.o:$(SRC)employee_functions.cpp $(INCLUDE)employee.h $(INCLUDE)main.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)employee_functions.cpp -I $(INCLUDE)
    mv main.o $(OBJ)                

$(OBJ)display.o:$(SRC)display.cpp $(INCLUDE)employee_data.h $(INCLUDE)application.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)display.cpp -I $(INCLUDE)
    mv main.o $(OBJ)

$(OBJ)error_function.o :$(SRC)error_function.cpp $(INCLUDE)main.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)error_function.cpp -I $(INCLUDE)
    mv main.o $(OBJ)

$(OBJ)thread.o:$(SRC)thread.cpp $(INCLUDE)employee.h $(INCLUDE)application.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)thread.cpp -I $(INCLUDE)
    mv main.o $(OBJ)
```

After runing make i got eroor like :

```
g++  ../src/main.cpp -I ../include/
/tmp/cc09snhj.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x568): undefined reference to `message::errormessage(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5fb): undefined reference to `message::errormessage(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6c5): undefined reference to `message::errormessage(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x758): undefined reference to `message::errormessage(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7f3): undefined reference to `message::errormessage(int)'
/tmp/cc09snhj.o: In function `implementation::implementation()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN14implementationC2Ev[_ZN14implementationC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for implementation'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../obj/main.o] Error 1
```

what is wrong on my code ? any problem in make file ? I think the problem is linking the header files . Is this correct way to link header files ? Please help me to get my make file work .

Comment: That's a lot files to consider... Did you already try to reduce your code (remove files) as to check what could have caused the error? It seems to have nothing to do with *multithreading* so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just misspelled `CFLAGS` in `CFLAGES=-c -Wall`

I'm guessing this is the case since

```
g++  ../src/main.cpp -I ../include/
```

does not have the `-c` option

Comment: oh god..it's my mistake ..works fine and also i changed " mv main.o $(OBJ) " to all codes ...it's work fine ..thanks